# Push notification doesn't work in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am using https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification. After doing all the setup my app runs but it doesn't show the notification. Here's the AndroidManifest.xml file of mine:

```js
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.movit_driver1">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <permission
    android:name="com.movit_driver1.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.movit_driver1.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

    <application
      android:name=".MainApplication"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:allowBackup="false"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
      
      <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
      </activity>
      <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" />
      <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyAbbD4N_pPzGPSPY_PyLy"/>
       <receiver
      android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
      android:exported="true"
      android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        <category android:name="com.movit_driver1" />
      </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <receiver android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.modules.RNPushNotificationPublisher" />
    <service android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.modules.RNPushNotificationRegistrationService"/>
    <service
      android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.modules.RNPushNotificationListenerService"
      android:exported="false" >
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
      </intent-filter>
    </service>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Here's the PushNotificationController.js file :

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PushNotification from 'react-native-push-notification';

export default class PushNotificationController extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    PushNotification.configure({
      onNotification: function(notification) {
        console.log( 'NOTIFICATION:', notification );
      },
    });
  }

  render() {
    return null;
  }
}
```

And finally my homescreen :

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Platform, StyleSheet, Text, View, Picker, AppState } from 'react-native';
import PushNotificationController from './PushNotification/PushNotificationController'
import PushNotification from 'react-native-push-notification';
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
      flex: 1,
      justifyContent: 'center',
      alignItems: 'center',
      backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
    },
    welcome: {
      fontSize: 20,
      textAlign: 'center',
      margin: 10,
    },
    instructions: {
      textAlign: 'center',
      color: '#333333',
      marginBottom: 5,
    },
    picker: {
      width: 100,
    },
  });

export default class HomeScreen extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    
        this.handleAppStateChange = this.handleAppStateChange.bind(this);
        this.state = {
          seconds: 5,
        };
      }
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Text style={styles.welcome}>
                Choose your notification time in seconds.
                </Text>
                <Picker
                style={styles.picker}
                selectedValue={this.state.seconds}
                onValueChange={(seconds) => this.setState({ seconds })}
                >
                <Picker.Item label="5" value={5} />
                <Picker.Item label="10" value={10} />
                <Picker.Item label="15" value={15} />
                </Picker>
                <PushNotificationController/>
            </View>
        );
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        AppState.addEventListener('change', this.handleAppStateChange);
      }
    
    componentWillUnmount() {
    AppState.removeEventListener('change', this.handleAppStateChange);
    }
    
    handleAppStateChange(appState) {
            if (appState === 'background') {
                let date = new Date(Date.now() + (this.state.seconds * 1000));
          
                if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
                  date = date.toISOString();
                }
          
                PushNotification.localNotificationSchedule({
                  message: "My Notification Message",
                  date,
                  soundName: "rush"
                });
        }
    }
}
```

**Additional Information:**

- React-native version:"0.57.5"
- Platform-OS : "android"

The app builds but doesn't show any notification. What am i missing here? Any help would be appreciated.Thanks.

Comment: Did you check if you are executing the block inside `handleAppStateChange`?

Comment: Unfortunately that is not executing as i did a console.log there. But i dont know why this is happening.

Comment: Okay,the handleAppStateChange is now executing but still no notification  @RudolfCicko

Comment: I would try also to remove the configuration code from a React Component (PushNotificationController) and put it in a normal function as in the example in the docs. You are not interested on rendering nothing so the React component there is quite useless.

Comment: Now the code is like this https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-6xgo7j  but still the same issue.

Comment: I can not try it now but this evening I can take a better look if you don't fix it. Only think more I can tell you is to check properly the linking with the library (android stuff mainly) because sometimes it may not be properly linked even if there is no error.